# How to keep dropdown open on mouse over?

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu

```
$("#home-shop-first").hover(function(){
    $("#first-button-box").slideToggle();
});
```

This works to display a dropdown box, but now I need to be able to add links to the content in this box and have the user able to mouse over and click them.

Can I just make changes to what I have or do I need to completely rethink this?

BTW - This is one of six, although neither of the ID'd divs are currently part of a list element. I'm happy to change that if it helps.

Comment: If you close the `#home-shop-first` element after the dropdown, when you move the mouse over the dropdown items, the mouse will remain hovering the element in the element will remain open...

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to jQuery and not quite sure how to do that?

Comment: Please show us your code, make a jsfiddle.

http://www.jsfiddle.net

Comment: Nothing to do with jQuery, just open the element identified as `#home-shop-first` before the `#first-button-box` and close it after the `#first-button-box`. Like so: `<div id="home-shop-first"><div id="first-button-box"></div></div>`

Comment: @user#######... lol... that's too easy. Of course, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you close the `#home-shop-first` element after the dropdown, when you move the mouse over the dropdown items, the mouse will remain hovering the element in the element will remain open...

Nothing to do with jQuery, just open the element identified as `#home-shop-first` before the `#first-button-box` and close it after the `#first-button-box`. Like so:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gygPh/

Comment: I was just about to suggest you create the answer since you answered me perfectly in comments. Thanks for not beating me up too bad for such a bonehead moment! :)

Answer (score 0):

In the case your `#first-button-box` is not embeded in your `#home-shop-first` you could simply bind a different event. Like 'mouseenter' :

```js
$("#home-shop-first").bind('mouseenter',function(){
    $("#first-button-box").slideToggle();
});​
```

There is many other solutions. I'd do something [like that](http://jsfiddle.net/gN2Jx/) if there is many elements to avoid an ID for each of your buttons if not necessary.